# accessing multiple virtual directories using a single web app

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, webforms, virtual-directory

Is it possible to look into multiple virtual directories, using a single web application?

I'm trying to develop a web app; which can create a site, save this site to a virtual directory in the same server, and make changes (i.e. add/edit webpages).

The web app will handle multiple domain names (IIS will handle the bindings going into the single web app), which are routed by the web app to their respective virtual directories.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: So long as your app has the permissions and knows where the folder is on the local path (the absolute path to the files) there would be no problem.

Comment: How can I access the other virtual directories? If I use the "~/" I just go to the root of the web app virtual directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a certain permissions in order to manipulate the IIS metabase. The default ASP.NET user account doesn't have such permissions so you might want to use an impersonation. You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (what is impersonation) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx) (how to impersonate programmatically).

To configure the IIS programmatically use the classes from the [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace. You can read more about how to do this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525791%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (tagged as for IIS6). You can also use the [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) namespace (which seems more specific to IIS7) but in this case you need to [download and install the corresponding SDK](http://forums.iis.net/p/1160664/1918506.aspx).

Hope I clarified things for you a bit.